# Too many open files python

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to resize images. It works fine, but my [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField), which is `to_field`, is opening but not closing. So I have an error `too many open files`. I tried some work-around solutions but I wasn't able to fix the problem. Here is the code:

```
if( to_field.width != size[0] and to_field.height != size[1] ):
   to_field.open()
   image = Image.open(StringIO(to_field.read()))
   old_file_path = to_field.path
   image.resize(size).save(to_field.path)
```

Any advice??

Comment: Did you/Should you `image.close()`? (Not familiar with PIL...)

Comment: yes, I tried. There is no attribute 'close'

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Close an Image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135328/how-to-close-an-image)

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I think it is the django field *to_field* that needs to be closed:

```
to_field.close()
```